# decompress LZW tif data by C#

Tags: tiff, lzw

I got the following information from Tiff file.

> ```
> ImageWidth Short 2977
> ImageLength Short 5613
> BitsPerSample Short 2
> Compression Short LZW  
> PhotometricInterpretation Short WhiteIsZero
> StripOffsets Long [(22)]
> SamplesPerPixel Short 1
> RowsPerStrip Short 256      
> StripByteCounts Long [(22)]
> ```

So I think the image data total bytes is 22*256.

How can I decompress the image data for a new bitmap?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you got this information from? Do you use .NET Framework or .NET Core? Do you have any code where you attempt to decompress the image?

Comment: Thanks your response! I got this informaition by .NET Framework (https://github.com/dgm9704/TIFF) . I have no proper decompress code in hand. Any decompress code  in C# will be help.

Comment: Following is the decode codes                                                                
`private List<byte[]> LZW_Decoder(List<byte[]> tifStripData)
        {
            List<byte[]> uncompressedList = new List<byte[]>();

            foreach (var stripe in tifStripData)
            {
                byte[] decodedBytes = OcfLzw.OcfLzw.Decode(stripe);
                uncompressedList.Add(decodedBytes);
            }

            return uncompressedList;
        }`

Comment: [https://github.com/pgodwin/OcfLzw/tree/master/OcfLzw]